# How to avoid socket disconnection while navigating to the screen where both screen are listing for socket event?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sockets, socket.io

I'm currently developing a Chat App that involves connecting and disconnecting sockets. I have three screens: EventList (Home), ChatList, and Chat.

The socket handling code, as shown below, is functional:

```
const socket = useRef<Socket>(null);

useEffect(() => {
  const SERVER_URL = SOCKET_URL;

  socket.current = io(SERVER_URL, {
    extraHeaders: { user: userInfo?.email },
  });

  socket.current.on('connect', () => {});

  socket.current.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error('error', error?.message);
  });

  socket.current.on('connect_error', (error) => {
    console.error('connect_error', error?.message);
  });

  socket.current.on('chat message', (data: ChatMessageType[]) => {});

  socket.current.on('messages_received', (data: MessagesReceivedType[]) => {});

  return () => {
    socket.current.disconnect();
  };
}, []);
```

My concern lies in the following code snippet, where the socket is disconnected upon navigating to the next screen:

```
return () => {
  socket.current.disconnect();
};
```

This results in the socket being disconnected and reconnected when switching between the Event List and Chat List screens, even though both screens are actively listening to the socket.

I aim to avoid this behavior and only disconnect the socket if the screen the user is navigating to does not listen for the socket. How can I achieve this more efficiently?

I attempted to address the issue by encapsulating the EventList and ChatList components within a single component named SocketManager, where I centralized the socket operations. Despite this effort, the problem persists, and the socket still connects and disconnects when navigating between the screens.